# C# which component for list application (table, list, ...)?

Tags: c#, .net, list, data-structures, panel

I'd like to make a form application that can hold links from Youtube, but I don't know which components should I use. I need maybe a list or table, every row is a element of the list, and I'd like to put a label, image or button in a column. It's a kind of list. What kind of component should I use?

Comment: Your title is not clear, fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a ListView control and add the columns as subitems.  This will allow you to put images, labels, etc in the subitems columns.  The ListView control is very flexible and should meet your needs.  Try out something like [this example](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2013/09/make-a-listview-control-display-icons-next-to-sub-items-in-c/).